# Why is my request body not being populated correctly

Tags: python, express, python-requests, http-get

I am trying to test a very simple Express App. I have my Express set up in a typescript file as follows to respond with the body of the request that it receives:

```
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.body)
});
```

I am trying to call this endpoint in a python file as follows

```
testUrl = 'http://localhost:3000'
path = '/test'
header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
body = {
    'artistName': 'test',
}
response = requests.request(
    method="GET",
    url = testUrl + path,
    params=header,
    data=body,
)
print(response._content)
```

When I run the python file, all it prints out is a set of empty brackets, telling me that the body of the request it is receiving is empty. Why is the body empty if I am setting the data parameter to a populated json object? Am I using the wrong parameters? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `json=` instead of `data=` if you are intending to encode the dict as json.

Comment: as @jordanm said use `json=` to send JSON data - It should also automatically add header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. You can test your requests also with url https://httpbin.org/get and it will send you back all what it get from you - so you can check if you correctly send data or you can compare with resutl from other tools

Comment: i run your code and it works correctly. Maybe add `console.log(req.body)` to see if you get it and to see if run correct code. It behaves like you run different JavaScript code.

Comment: BTW: to set headers you have to use `headers=` instead of `params=` but code works for me even without headers. `params=` sends values in url like `test?name=value`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean to do with `res.send(req.body)` in your Express code, but `req.body` is not used for a GET request in Express.  That's used for a `POST` or `PUT`.

Parameters for a GET request are put in the URL as part of the queryString and will appear in the `req.query` object in Express.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is in the request,

Because you are sending your header as params